# Rank of the entry-wise-product of an orthogonal matrix and its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $P$ be an $n \times n$ real-valued orthogonal matrix, ie, such that $ P P^\top = I_n$. Consider the matrix $M$:
$$ M_{i,j} = P_{i,j} P_{j,i} \ , \ \ i,j = 1,..,n.  $$
Is it possible that rank$(M) \leq n-2 \ $?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $M$ can even be $0$. For example, let
$$P=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0
\end{pmatrix}.$$
More generally, let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ be the natural basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $\sigma:\{1,2,\dots,n\}\to\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ be a permutation which satisfies that $\sigma(\sigma(i))\ne i$,  $1\le i\le n$. Then for $P$ defined by $$P(e_i)=e_{\sigma(i)},\quad1\le i\le n,$$ $P$ is orthogonal and the associated $M$ is $0$.